# Read text in excell cell, then find corresponding folder

Tags: search, uipath

I want to read the text from excel and find the corresponding folder in windows.
Let say, I have excel file containing the list of folder I want to open in file explorer.

[image: my list folder in excel]

and here is my folder.

[image: folder in dekstop]

So I want to read from excel file on cell A2, then after read “dotnet”, I want to find in the screen, where is “dotnet” folder. I have tried using function “text exist”. However, it wasnt working.
Can anybody tell me which function should I use to find the corresponding folder?

Answer (score 1):

Use read range activity to read all data from excel. Once you have the directory, use for each item in data table, you can simply open run command with send hot key (win + r) and type into your directory.
That should open the folder up for you.